# Where is "F2" button on an Xbox controller?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, microsoft-flight-simulator

On Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020, on an Xbox Series X, the first of the flight-training modules teaches how to move the camera and save that view. Then the tutorial orders me to restore the original camera view by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>. I cannot progress further until I press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

What is the <kbd>F2</kbd> button on the bundled Xbox controller?

Is this a flaw in their Flight Training tutorial, expecting the game to be played on a PC with <kbd>F2</kbd> key on an attached keyboard?

Comment: According to Reddit, there's a controller guide in the toolbar. Alternatively you can see all your key bindings in the settings page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this when using the bundled wireless Xbox controller while a flight controller ([*Thrustmaster T.Flight Hotas One*](https://www.thrustmaster.com/en-us/products/t-flight-hotas-one/)) was simultaneously plugged in. The flight controller does offer a `F2` button (middle top of joystick). The *Flight Training* module of Microsoft Flight Simulator does adjust its directions according what controller is plugged in.

The Xbox does not seem to tolerate well having multiple controllers at the same time. **Use only one controller at a time.**

- Unplug the flight controller, and reboot to use the wireless Xbox controller, OR
- Leave the wireless Xbox turned off (or remove batteries), and reboot Xbox with the flight controller plugged in.